# Trigger using Teamcity Kotlin DSL

Tags: teamcity, kotlin, teamcity-10

I have Teamcity job defined in Kotlin and I want to add a trigger.

I used:

```
buildType {
    triggers {
        trigger {
            type = "VCS Trigger"
            enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

But this results to 
[image: unknown build trigger]

What definition should I use to have proper VCS trigger in place

Answer (score 8):

I found the way to do it using **vcs** directive.

Note, you have to import trigger class

```
buildType {
    triggers {
        vcs {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, you need `import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.triggers.vcs`